# How long does it take for a fruit tree to fill up before it needs to be harvested?

Tags: stardew-valley

I noticed that fruit trees don't need to be harvested everyday when they've matured. If you wait 2 days, then the tree will have 2 fruit instead of 1.

**So how long does it take for a fruit tree to fill up with the maximum amount of fruit that it can hold?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some testing, I found that **fruit trees can hold a maximum of 3 fruit**, so it takes 3 days for a tree to reach its max limit before it needs to be harvested.